# How to add the custom shipping method in woo commerce with out use the woocommerce default shipping options?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am developing an extension for woo commerce WordPress plugin.i want add the custom shipping method with out using the admin panel shipping method, i want to use temporary shipping method to display no need to register the shipping method  how?

Answer (score 0):

you can find all information about the new Shipping Method API (since 2.6) here: https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/wiki/Shipping-Method-API-(2.6)

Quick Answer: if you would like to add a new Shipping Method simply use

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_methods', 'register_test_method' );

function register_test_method( $methods ) {
   $methods[ 'test_method' ] = 'WC_Shipping_Test_Method';
   return $methods;
}
```

Just found this gist as well, made by Mike Jolley:
https://gist.github.com/mikejolley/3b37b9cc19a774665f31

Let me know if you need any help implementing this.

Comment: ,Thanks for your post , I already tried that one its working .. but i will add as a extra shipping method in check out shows the shipping option.. But my requirement is  with out enable the shipping option will use the custom  static shipping ,method show in checkout page  ..

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking. Do you want to add a Shipping Method, or not? Maybe you can add it and set it as not available to be used in cart.